# Create product with json request using SOAP API in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, soap-api-v2

How to create simple product with json request using SOAP API in magento?

Answer (score 0):

That's a very vague, broad question. You're asking for an entire lesson on Magento flow and implementation. What have you tried to far? What exactly is the problem you're running into right now?

I reckon there's a route to a controller somewhere that takes a data array which will create a product from that data.